# A x-axis at top of ggplot with different labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add some labels on the top of the plot in line with the x-axis. How can I add the displacement in cm3 to the top of this plot so that I have cubic inches at the bottom and cubic cm at the top? Should I do it with annotate? What about tick marks? I realize this makes an ugly graph in this case. [Edited for clarity.]

```
# Calculate displacement in cm3 -- add this to top of plot 
# above 100, 200, 300, 400 ticks and labels for cubic inches on bottom
cm3.lab <- seq(100,400,100) * 16.3871
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg))
p + geom_point(size=5) + xlab("Cubic inches")
p
```

Comment: p + geom_point(size=5) + xlab("Cubic inches") seems to give you want to want

Answer (score 2):

You can get finer control over the label & tick marks with `scale_x_continuous`:

```
p + geom_point(size=5) + scale_x_continuous(name="Displacement in cubic centimeters", breaks = c(100, 200, 300, 400), labels=c("100" = "100", "200" = "200", "300" = "300", "400" = "400"));
```

See `?scale_x_continuous` for more options

Note: Cubic centimeters and cubic inches are not the same thing. Be sure to pick the right one!